# About to store multiple values of child checkbox related to parent checkbox, data is stored only one time

Tags: php, checkbox

When I store services and activity then services and activity value store multiple times in the database, I also use implode instead of foreach but that time first service and first activity stored, the following image describes the idea about what I exactly want.

```
<form method='post' id='userform' action='savecheckbox.php'> <tr>
<td>Trouble Type</td>
<br>
<td>
 <input type='checkbox' name='servicevar[]' value='1'>tds<br>    <br>

<input type='checkbox' name='activityvar[]' value='1'>Return<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='activityvar[]' value='2'>Filling<br>
<br>


 <input type='checkbox' name='servicevar[]' value='2'>Gst<br>    <br>
<td>

<input type='checkbox' name='activityvar[]' value='1'>Return<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='activityvar[]' value='2'>Filling<br>
<br>

<input type='checkbox' name='servicevar[]' value='3'>vat<br>    <br>
<td>

<input type='checkbox' name='activityvar[]' value='1'>Return<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='activityvar[]' value='2'>Filling<br>
<br>
</td> </tr> </table> <input type='submit' name="submit" class='buttons'>
```

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $activity = $_POST['activityvar'];
    $service = $_POST['servicevar'];

    foreach ($service as $key => $servicevalue)
    {
        foreach($activity as $key=>$activityvalue)
        {
            $query = "insert into serviceacitivitymap(service_id,activity_id)values('$servicevalue','$activityvalue')";
            $insert_row = $conn->query($query) or die ($conn->error.__LINE__);
        }
    }
}
```

?>

- **Recent output image**

[image]

- **expected output image**

[image]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQE6W.png):

Comment: You are reasigning the `$key` in your foreach, define the `$key` for activity as `$key2`

Comment: the problem is same again when i rename $key to $key2

Comment: Try "echo $query" after the row where you define "$query" and show us the output.

Comment: insert into serviceacitivitymap(service_id,activity_id)values('1','1')
insert into serviceacitivitymap(service_id,activity_id)values('1','2')
insert into serviceacitivitymap(service_id,activity_id)values('1','1')
insert into serviceacitivitymap(service_id,activity_id)values('1','2')
insert into serviceacitivitymap(service_id,activity_id)values('1','1')
insert into serviceacitivitymap(service_id,activity_id)values('1','2')
same for service 2 and service 3

Comment: Do you have a big HTML structure than the posted here or just 3 services/6 activities? do you have the  full control on the HTML posted?

Comment: yes i have 13 or more services and 30 activities and also periodicity is included means 1 service 30 activity 5 periodicity like this 13 or mores services and the data is come from database in checkbox value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HTML:-<form method='post' id='userform' action='sh.php'> <tr>
<td>Trouble Type</td>
<br>
<td>
 <input type='checkbox' name="arr[1][service]" value='1'>tds<br>    <br>

<input type='checkbox' name="arr[1][activity][]" value='1'>Return<br>
<input type='checkbox' name="arr[1][activity][]" value='2'>Filling<br>
<br>


 <input type='checkbox' name="arr[2][service]" value='2'>Gst<br>    <br>
<td>

<input type='checkbox' name="arr[2][activity][]" value='1'>Return<br>
<input type='checkbox' name="arr[2][activity][]" value='2'>Filling<br>
<br>

<input type='checkbox' name="arr[3][service]" value='3'>vat<br>    <br>
<td>

<input type='checkbox' name="arr[3][activity][]" value='1'>Return<br>
<input type='checkbox' name="arr[3][activity][]" value='2'>Filling<br>
<br>
</td> </tr> </table> <input type='submit' name="submit" class='buttons'>
```

```
PHP:-<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    foreach ($_POST['arr'] as $input) {

      foreach ($input['activity'] as $activity) {

        $servicevalue = $input['service'];


        $query = "insert into serviceacitivitymap(service_id,activity_id)
                    values('$servicevalue','$activity')";
        $insert_row=$conn->query($query) or die ($conn->error.__LINE__);
        echo $query;
        echo "<br>";

      }
    }

}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

This code Should work for you,

Your HTML Code,

```
<form method='post' id='userform' action='savecheckbox.php'> <tr>
<td>Trouble Type</td>
<br>
<td>
 <input type='checkbox' name='servicevar[]' value='1'>tds<br>    <br>

<input type='checkbox' name='activityvar[1][]' value='1'>Return<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='activityvar[1][]' value='2'>Filling<br>
<br>


 <input type='checkbox' name='servicevar[]' value='2'>Gst<br>    <br>
<td>

<input type='checkbox' name='activityvar[2][]' value='1'>Return<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='activityvar[2][]' value='2'>Filling<br>
<br>

<input type='checkbox' name='servicevar[]' value='3'>vat<br>    <br>
<td>

<input type='checkbox' name='activityvar[3][]' value='1'>Return<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='activityvar[3][]' value='2'>Filling<br>
<br>
</td> </tr> </table> <input type='submit' name="submit" class='buttons'>
```

savecheckbox.php

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $activity = $_POST['activityvar'];
    $service = $_POST['servicevar'];
    foreach ($service as $key=>$servicevalue)
    {
        foreach($servicevalue as $activityvalue)
        {
            $query = "insert into serviceacitivitymap(service_id,activity_id)values('$key','$activityvalue')";
            $insert_row = $conn->query($query) or die ($conn->error.__LINE__);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi it work for when i check all checkbox,but when i check 1,2 activity in 1 st service 1 st activity in 2 nd service then it store like 1->1,1->2,2->1,2->2

Comment: I got issue, i have updated my answer please try . updated code

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 0):

You have to use associative arrays in the name of input's like :

```
<form method='post' id='userform'>
  <tr>
    <td>Trouble Type</td>
    <br>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' name='servicevar[]' value='1'>tds<br> <br>

      <input type='checkbox' name='activityvar[1][]' value='1'>Return<br>
      <input type='checkbox' name='activityvar[1][]' value='2'>Filling<br>
      <br>


      <input type='checkbox' name='servicevar[]' value='2'>Gst<br> <br>
      <td>

        <input type='checkbox' name='activityvar[2][]' value='1'>Return<br>
        <input type='checkbox' name='activityvar[2][]' value='2'>Filling<br>
        <br>

        <input type='checkbox' name='servicevar[]' value='3'>vat<br> <br>
        <td>

          <input type='checkbox' name='activityvar[3][]' value='1'>Return<br>
          <input type='checkbox' name='activityvar[3][]' value='2'>Filling<br>
          <br>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table> 
<input type='submit' name="submit" class='buttons'>
```

Then in your php code you could loop through them like :

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $services = $_POST['servicevar'];
        $activities = $_POST['activityvar'];

        foreach ($services as $service)
        {
            foreach($activities[$service] as $activity)
            {
                $query = "insert into serviceacitivitymap(service_id,activity_id) values('$service','$activity')";
                $insert_row = $conn->query($query) or die ($conn->error.__LINE__);
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: @Rutu here we go, this is the solution you're searching for, you could check/uncheck what you want and just the checked data will be stored in the Database.

Comment: sir the code is working correctly..can i ask u one query??Thankss

Comment: hi,if the value of service and activity  of checkbox is come from databse then what to do

Comment: Do you mean you want to check/uncheck them by default according to the db values?

Comment: yes if  the value of service and activity is dynamic then what will be the name of service and activity in html input tag

Comment: Do you have those names stored in the database? example 'service_name' in 'services' table or 'activity_name' in 'activities' table ? I mean `tds,Gst,vat`...

Comment: sir i post my question with my tried code on stack overflow ,can u cyeheck plzz??yes i have service and activity seperate tables and i want to be store all service and activity checked value in mapserviceactivity table for my project